# How do I kill a certain entity in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a Minecraft map. When you stand on a pressure plate, a squid has to die. The squid is at position `[831, 65, -232]`.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @RudolfJelínek And we expect users to show **effort** to answer their own questions.  Not doing so is not a good sign.

Answer (score 4):

To kill your squid, if its exactly in that coordinate, use

```
/kill @e[type=Squid,x=831,y=65,z=-232,r=0]
```

This will kill all squids that are at the coordinates 831,65,-232 with a range of 0. The range of 0 means that only the squids on that coordinate will be killed.

---

To be a little more secure, use this command:

```
/kill @e[type=Squid,x=831,y=65,z=-232,r=0,c=1]
```

This will only kill the nearest squid that is on the coordinates 831,65,-232 with a maximum range of 0 so only the squid that is on that coordinate is killed.

Comment: I don't think `r=0` works anymore, you should now use `dx=0`, `dy=0`, or `dz=0`

Comment: @kabiroberai it works, but I'm not sure if with `r=0`, I would suggest to type `r=1`

Comment: @RudolfJelínek In 1.8 it only kills the mobs with exactly that coordinate. I tried to use `r=1` and spawn mobs in a circle around the coordinate and they all died. Wirth `r=0` only the center one did. I'm not sure if this also applies to 1.9, I'm going to try this out now and see if it does. If it doesn't I will update the question.

Answer (score 3):

To find the entity name, type /summon and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get a full list of entities.

To kill them, type

```
/kill @e[type=ENTITY]
```

where ENTITY is your entity.

To kill them at the coordinates, simply use the X, Y, and Z, tags.

Your new command should look like this:

```
/kill @e[type=Squid,x=831,y=65,z=-232]
```

Comment: Be aware that without an area limiter such as `r` or `dx/dy/dz`, all squids will be killed. All that was changed is the origin, which is essentially no different than not changing it (the actual difference being the order in which targets are obtained).

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can do it a different way by adding a tag to the squid and kill any squid with that tag.

```
/kill @e[type=entity,tag=tagname]
```

Entity would be minecraft:the entity you want and tagname is the tag's name that you put on the squid.